# Reach GeoServer layers from outside

Tags: geoserver

I have installed successfully GeoServer in a Windows machine as well as create some stores and layers.

I would like to be able to reach the available data via a GET request from outside.
I cannot find out how i have to configure the GeoServer or/and the machine in order to be able to do it.

Here is an example of a GET request:

http://SERVER_IP:8080/geoserver/test/wms?LAYERS=eu_dem_v11,polygonsArea,roads&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap bbox=104011.35281299074%2C3850810.9991870853%2C1007936.4227139263%2C4623914.497431942&width=768&height=656&srs=EPSG%3A2100&styles=&format=application/openlayers

Can you please give me some references?

Comment: I think you need to set your firewall to allow port 8080 for other machine to access your port. If you want it to be accessible over the internet, then learn port forwarding; set your router to forward port 8080 to your machine. I don't think this is a geoserver issue.

Comment: What response do you get?

Comment: I am not sure if it is only the port, i got back a Server Connection Timeout error.